# How to display my tabs verticalcenter in android

Tags: android, android-tabs

I  am very new to android ,I displaying tabs its working fine but ,I want show      it in center of the screen  in android ,here below my code ,I change in heghit as 245dp but it showing not prefect output it will display some gap in between tab and indicator How to display my tabs like below image and how to display my app name like in image any one please help me,Thank you in advance

```
activity_main.xml
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

[image]

Comment: use weightSum to get it in center

Answer (score 0):

check this code you will find the solution :
  https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager